# Abstract Data Type implementation in Procedural Programming

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

I have a question for the more advanced OOP developers here.
I am currently a CS student. We learned a Procedural Programming in Java the first semester where ADT was introduced. I understand the theory and the idea of why ADT is good and what are the benefits of it but it seems quite difficult for me to implement it in code. I get confused and lost.
In addition to that our exit test was on paper (we had to write around 200 line of code on paper) and I found it difficult.
Are there any tips before starting to construct the program?
For instance, do you guys already know how many methods and what method what it will return and have as a formal argument before you start to write the code?

Comment: There are no fixed requirements on how many methods an ADT should have. Even one with a single method can be an ADT. There are many ADTs in the Java API already, such as `String` and `BigInteger`. Maybe study those?

Comment: write and design code that is easy to change/delete. TDD is really helpful in this aspect. It will also help with maintenance later down the road. Remember: code always chages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach it programming-style.

First, you need to define an interface for the ADT. Just write down its name and what it does.

Example:

> ADT: Integer Stack
>
> - `void push(int element)` - adds an element to the top of stack
> - `int pop()` - removes and returns an element from the top of stack
> - `int peek()` - returns the value of top. no removal of value
> - `boolean isEmpty()` - returns true if the stack is empty
> - `int size()` - returns the number of element in the stack.
> - `void print()` - print all values of stack

Next is you need to decide on its implementation. Since ADT is about storage, it will be good to decide on storage strategy first.

Example:

> ADT: Integer Stack
>
> Implementation: Array Integer Stack
>
> - Implements an int stack using Java's built-in array functionality.
> - Since array is a static collection, i need to use an integer variable to track "top"

When everything is set, you can now proceed to coding.

```
public interface IntegerStack {
  void push(int e);
  int pop();
  int peek();
  boolean isEmpty();
  int size();
  void print();
}

public class ArrayIntegerStack implements IntegerStack {
  private static final int INITIAL_TOP_INDEX = -1;

  private int topIndex = INITIAL_TOP_INDEX;
  private int[] stackValue = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];

  @Override
  public void push(int element) {
    stackValue[++topIndex] = element;
  }

  @Override
  public int pop() {
    return stackValue[topIndex--];
  }

  @Override
  public int peek() {
    return stackValue[topIndex];
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return INITIAL_TOP_INDEX == topIndex;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return topIndex + 1;
  }

  @Override
  public void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= topIndex; i++) {
      System.out.println(stackValue[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation, even though `new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` would cause an `OutOfMemoryError` before you've even started.

Comment: This really helped me get my head around it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the answer of KaNa001, you could use a modified HashMap where the key is the index and the value is the integer in the stack. This wont cause an Exception, as the HashMap object can change its length.

```
public class OrderSet<T> {

private HashMap<Integer, T> array;

public OrderSet() {

    array = new HashMap<Integer, T>();
}

public void addAt (T o, int pos) {
    // uses Array indexing

    HashMap<Integer, T> temp = new HashMap<Integer, T>();

    if (!(array.size() == 0)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {

            temp.put(i, array.get(i));
        }

        array.put(pos, o);

        int size = array.size();

        for (int i = pos + 1; i < size + 1; i++) {

            array.put(i, temp.get(i - 1));
        }
    } else {

        array.put(0, o);
    }
}

public T getPos (int pos) {

    if (array.size() == 0) {

        return null;
    } else {

        return array.get(pos);
    }
}
}
```